# Google Script: Delete row if a value in it exists in another sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a question with Google Scripting. I just started using Google Script this February so I  don't have deep understanding with it yet. Anyway my question is:

Can I delete a row if certain values of it exist in another sheet? I tried several concepts I found in the internet but I was not able to come up with a working function.

Here's the [Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AgvpJFmpMsvrdGlKVENpMGRNZ1lxWGc2ZEpGczNzN1E&usp=sharing) for a detailed view.

For example, in Sheet 1 I have two rows:

---

***NAME | PLACE | AGE***

Carl |  Florida | 45

Mike |  Florida | 41

---

And in Sheet 2:

---

***NAME | PLACE | AGE***

Mike |  Florida | 41

---

The script should delete Mike Florida row in Sheet 1 since it has duplicate data in Sheet 2. So basically, if data in Sheet 2 exists in Sheet 1, it should be deleted in Sheet 1. But the tricky part is, I have to compare column 1 and column 2 only. Column 3 is not important. If column 1 and 2 in Sheet 2 have the same exact value in Sheet 1, it should be deleted in Sheet 1 and data in Sheet 2 should remain.

I tried this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/removing_duplicates) in Google site but still I was not able to compare the two sheets and remove the duplicate data.

Thank you so much. Any help/idea/advice will be greatly appreciated. :)

+++++++++

I just came up with a code now and used 2D Arrays Library.

```
function deleteRowInSheet1() { 
   var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("COPY SPREADSHEET ID HERE").getSheetByName('Sheet1');
   var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("COPY SPREADSHEET ID HERE").getSheetByName('Sheet2'); 
   var values1 = s1.getDataRange().getValues();
   var values2 = s2.getDataRange().getValues();
  // Check if Mike exists in SS1.
  if (ArrayLib.find(values2, 0, 'Mike') != -1) {
    for( var row = values1.length -1; row >= 0; --row ) {
      if (values1[row][0] == 'Mike')
      s1.deleteRow(parseInt(row)+1);
    }
  }
}
```

But, this code only gets specific value which is Mike. If row Mike exists in Sheet 2, row Mike in Sheet 1 will be deleted too. I tried modifying the code more to compare the two values from the two different sheets but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: just a detail question : should the script also check for duplicates in sheet 1 or is this not going to happen ?

Comment: Hi @Sergeinsas, that part will not happen since Sheet 1 contents are unique. I was able to come up with a working code just now almost similar to what I need. But I still have a problem though. I updated my question. You might have any idea on comparing the two values with my current code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with the 2D array library you use is that the `find` method returns an integer corresponding to its position in the array, which is not really a helpful information for you in this case.
I'd sugggest to loop in both arrays (which is very quick) and use a boolean to determine if we keep (or not) the values in sheet1.
Here is the code I used for testing and it seems to work as expected.

```
function deleteRowInSheet1() { 
  var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1RxtFWZJRWxgW-zUM6S-dvZ0yFe-G2DGJFWI3gAt-1T0").getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1RxtFWZJRWxgW-zUM6S-dvZ0yFe-G2DGJFWI3gAt-1T0").getSheetByName('Sheet2'); 
  var values1 = s1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var values2 = s2.getDataRange().getValues();
  var resultArray = [];
  for(var n in values1){
    var keep = true
    for(var p in values2){
      if( values1[n][0] == values2[p][0] && values1[n][1] == values2[p][1]){
        keep=false ; break ;
      }
    }
    if(keep){ resultArray.push(values1[n])};
  }
  s1.clear()
  s1.getRange(1,1,resultArray.length,resultArray[0].length).setValues(resultArray);
}
```

As you can see I delete the whole sheet to rebuild it with a new data array but doing this I loose any formatting that might have been present. If that's an issue for you then you'll have to use `clearContents()` instead. [See doc here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#clearContents%28%29) but delete any formatting in every unused rows below the last row... not very hard to implement I guess.

Comment: Hi @Sergeinsas! :) Thanks for these. I'll give it a shot. I'll update you if I had it working. :)

Comment: It worked as expected. :) I just edited the code to satisfy the output I need. Thank you so much! :)