# Google Script: Copy row if a value does exist in another sheet

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been working on this project and can't get it to work quite the way I want. I just started using Google Scripts and I don't have a very extensive knowledge of it.

I am needing to copy data from the master into sheet2 only if it does not exist in sheet2 already. I just want to check the Submission Date column (for now) against the two sheets.

## Master

### Submission Date

9/3/2014 10:37:04

9/3/2014 20:03:27

9/4/2014 0:47:14

9/4/2014 14:23:22

9/4/2014 14:31:49

9/4/2014 15:48:41

9/4/2014 15:55:16

9/5/2014 10:54:10

## Sheet2

### Submission Date

9/3/2014 10:37:04

9/3/2014 20:03:27

I need the last 6 Submission Dates in Master to copy to Sheet2. I've tried various codes and this is the last iteration I'm working with, partly borrowed from this post: [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008331/google-script-delete-row-if-a-value-in-it-exists-in-another-sheet)

```
function updateSheet() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sourceSheet = "Submissions"; 
var destinationSheet = "Applicant";
var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheet);
var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheet);
var lastCol = target_sheet.getLastColumn();
var lastRow = target_sheet.getLastRow();

//assumes headers in row 1
var r = target_sheet.getRange(2,1, lastRow - 1, lastCol);

//Note the use of an array
r.sort([{column: 1, ascending: true}]);


  // Process sheet
  _updateSpreadsheet(source_sheet, target_sheet);

}


function _updateSpreadsheet(source_sheet, target_sheet) {
var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();  
var source_data = source_sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var target_data = target_sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var resultArray = [];

for (var n in source_data) {
  var keep = true;
   for(var p in target_data) {
      if (source_data[n][0] == target_data[p][0]) {
                 keep = false; break;
      }
    }

    // If no duplicate, add to sheet
if(keep){ resultArray.push(source_data[n])};
last_row++;
target_sheet.getRange("A"+last_row).setValue(source_data[n][0]);
target_data.push(n);

  }
}
```

Instead of just adding the last records, it adds all of the records.

Clearly I'm missing something but I can't figure it out. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date comparison are not as simple as "normal" variable comparison..., we have to get the date native value to be able to get an equal condition.*(it works for > and < though)*

Below is the modified function  :

note that I restricted the range to avoid including headers in the comparison in both for loops
Also : I don't understand the last statement so I commented it.

```
function _updateSpreadsheet(source_sheet, target_sheet) {
  var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();  
  var source_data = source_sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var target_data = target_sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var resultArray = [];

  for (var n = 1 ; n < source_data.length ; n++) {
    var keep = true;
    for(var p = 1 ; p < target_data.length ; p++) {
      if (new Date(source_data[n][0]).getTime() == new Date(target_data[p][0]).getTime()) {
        keep = false; break;
      }
    }
    Logger.log(keep);
    if(keep){ resultArray.push([source_data[n][0]])};
  }
  last_row++;
  Logger.log(resultArray);
  target_sheet.getRange(last_row,1,resultArray.length,resultArray[0].length).setValues(resultArray);
//  target_data.push(n);
}
```

See also the Logger I added, it helped me to check what was happening ;-)

### EDIT :

I wasn't sure wether you wanted to copy the row or just the cell in column A... if you want to copy the row use this :

```
if(keep){ resultArray.push(source_data[n])};
```

---

### EDIT 2 :

Following your comment, here is a version that copies only certain columns in the target sheet:

(insert this part in existing code)

```
     ...
//   if(keep){ resultArray.push(source_data[n])};
//   if(keep){ resultArray.push([source_data[n][0]])};
    var columnsToKeep = [0,1,3,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,21,22];
    var tempData = [];
    if(keep){
      for(var c in columnsToKeep){ tempData.push(source_data[n][columnsToKeep[c]])};
    resultArray.push(tempData);
    }     
  }
  last_row++;
  ...
```

---

### EDIT 3 :

**final code for readability**

```
function _updateSpreadsheet(source_sheet, target_sheet) {
  var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();  
  var source_data = source_sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var target_data = target_sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var resultArray = [];

  for (var n = 1 ; n < source_data.length ; n++) {
    var keep = true;
    for(var p = 1 ; p < target_data.length ; p++) {
      if (new Date(source_data[n][0]).getTime() == new Date(target_data[p][0]).getTime()) {
        keep = false; break;
      }
    }
    Logger.log(keep);
 //   if(keep){ resultArray.push(source_data[n])};
//    if(keep){ resultArray.push([source_data[n][0]])};
    var columnsToKeep = [0,1,3,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,21,22];
    var tempData = [];
    if(keep){
      for(var c in columnsToKeep){ tempData.push(source_data[n][columnsToKeep[c]])}
    resultArray.push(tempData);
    }     
  }
  last_row++;
  Logger.log(resultArray);
  if(resultArray.length>0){
    target_sheet.getRange(last_row,1,resultArray.length,resultArray[0].length).setValues(resultArray);
  }
}
```

Comment: While this does do what I want in a small sample, my data contains over 1500 rows in each sheet and times out before it is finished. This may be a separate question... but any tips on getting the function processed before the maximum time has been exceeded? Thanks

Comment: I'm surprised... can you look at the execution transcript to see what is taking time ? this function works at array level and is very fast (normally). thx

Comment: It doesn't look like anything is taking a long time to execute. I see Logger.log([true, []]) [0 seconds] repeated 1,319. I'm assuming that's from looking at each row. Thanks

Comment: It should be quite easy to modify that script to make it handle smaller sets of data automatically...if you post a new thread on that particular point I'll be happy to answer (or someone else of course :-) - In the mean time could you accept this one as it solved the initial issue. Thx.

Comment: I have one more questions before I complete this thread. Is there a way to only push certain columns instead of just one or the entire row? Thanks

Comment: sure ;-) which one for example ? can it be hardcoded ?

Comment: Well... it's several. 0,1,3,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,21 & 22.

Comment: Thank you for the update. It works, but for some reason the validation check to keep the data is not working. It's adding all data from the master even if it exists in Sheet2. When looking at the execution log, I don't ever see any logger.log return false. I have 286 as true which equals the number of records in my test data. If I do a comparison within the cell versus the matching cell in the other sheet, it returns true. What could be happening? Is this also why it could be timing out? Thanks

Comment: this is a link to my working test sheet, make a copy and get the script from there... maybe you made a small error while updating the script. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gs0SgxKNQ0sOvzR3bCUILrzlso78corCTvYsgYJ5L3g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I think the error was with my data and formatting. One last thing before I move onto a new thread... what if there isn't any data to add? Can I stop the function before it gets to the last line? When there isn't data to add, it's errors on the last line. Thanks

Comment: Add a condition on resultArray.length >0 before writing to the ss.

Comment: Perfect! I'm going to test my data again and will start another thread if necessary. I'll also post my final code. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I hope this is the last question I have... the user decided they wanted the column order moved around. There are now 3 blank columns (not to be filled in from the array) in between columns 7 & 8. I've tried adding columnsToKeep.splice(6,0," "," "," "); but it's still not appending correctly. Any tips? Thanks

Comment: I figured my last question out. I needed to change the tempData variable to = columnsToKeep.splice(). Thanks