# Delete row values in more than 1 sheet if exists in another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The code below is from an answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26603110/copy-row-values-to-a-new-sheet-if-it-exist-in-another-sheet) regarding copying row values to a new sheet if it exist in another sheets.

Now, what if instead of copying the duplicate values to sheet 3, I want to delete them from sheets 1 and 2 if it exists in Sheet 3. With the same [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RlQTLZyPLasoJGplKemKg9qgcLcvCZZ_tPn6lWXEePw/edit?pli=1#gid=0), I have 3 sheets. The unique value that will be compared on the first 2 sheets is the first column, "ID NUMBER".

Given the values, `784  |   John Steep  | I.T Department`, which exists in all 3 sheets, the same row value should be deleted in Sheet 1 and 2 and retain the same value on Sheet 3.

```
function copyRowtoSheet3() { 
  var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName('Sheet2'); 
  var s3 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName('Sheet3'); 
  var values1 = s1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var values2 = s2.getDataRange().getValues();
  var resultArray = [];
  for(var n=0; n < values1.length ; n++){
    var keep = false;
    for(var p=0; p < values2.length ; p++){
      Logger.log(values1[n][0]+' =? '+values2[p][0]);
      if( values1[n][0] == values2[p][0] && values1[n][3] == values2[p][4]){
        resultArray.push(values1[n]);
        Logger.log('true');
        break ;// remove this if values are not unique and you want to keep all occurrences...
      }
    }
  }  
  s3.getRange(+1,1,resultArray.length,resultArray[0].length).setValues(resultArray);
}
```

Can't seem to find the right solution. Tried several scripts but failed to make it work.

Thank you for any advice/suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the other answer works (I didn't test but I guess it does) it uses a lot of spreadsheetApp calls and might be slow if you have a lot of data.

It is possible to get this result using only arrays (if you don't need to keep sheet formatting and/or formulas).

The approach is slightly different as it is easier to keep data instead of removing it.

There are for sure many possible solutions, below is the one I tried : I created a special array that contains only the first column of sheet3 to make the duplicate search simpler.

```
function removeDupsInOtherSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getDataRange().getValues();  
  var s2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getDataRange().getValues(); 
  var s3 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3").getDataRange().getValues();  
  // iterate s3 and check in s1 & s2 if duplicate values exist
  var nS1 = [];
  var nS2 = [];
  var s3Col1 = [];// data in column1 of sheet3
  for(var n in s3){
    s3Col1.push(s3[n][0]);
  }
  for(var n in s1){ // iterate sheet1 and test col 1 vs col 1 in sheet3
    var noDup1 = checkForDup(s1[n],s3Col1)
    if(noDup1){nS1.push(noDup1)};// if not present in sheet3 then keep
  } 
  for(var n in s2){  // iterate sheet2 and test col 1 vs col 1 in sheet3
    var noDup2 = checkForDup(s2[n],s3Col1)
    if(noDup2){nS2.push(noDup2)};// if not present in sheet3 then keep
  }
  Logger.log(nS1);// view result
  Logger.log(nS2);
  ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getDataRange().clear();// clear and update sheets
  ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getDataRange().clear();
  ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(1,1,nS1.length,nS1[0].length).setValues(nS1);
  ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange(1,1,nS2.length,nS2[0].length).setValues(nS2);
}

function checkForDup(item,s){
  Logger.log(s+' = '+item[0]+'  ?')
    if(s.indexOf(item[0])>-1){
      return null;
    }
  return item;
}
```

Comment: I opted instead to provide something easy to understand (although, admittedly, inefficient) in the event that the OP needs to modify and extend the function.

Comment: Hi @Serge Insas. I tried the script you provided and it works perfectly. I just modified some few code to satisfy my other specs. You're a genius! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

**Sheet1**

```
ID NUMBER   NAME        DEPARTMENT
784         John Steep  I.T.
901         Liz Green   H.R.
```

**Sheet2**

```
ID NUMBER   NAME        DEPARTMENT
784         John Steep  I.T.
653         Bo Gore     Marketing
```

**Sheet3**

```
ID NUMBER   NAME        DEPARTMENT
784         John Steep  I.T.
999         Frank White Sales
121         Abid Jones  Engineering
901         Liz Green   H.R.
```

**Script**

```
function main() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");

  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");  
  var s2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");  
  var s3 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3");  

  var idCol = 1;  // Assuming location of ID column is same in all sheets.

  var s1RowCount = s1.getLastRow();  

  for (var i = 2; i <= s1RowCount; i++) {  // Start at var i = 2 to skip the 
                                           // first row containing the header.
    var id = s1.getRange(i, idCol, 1, 1).getValue();
    deleteDuplicates(s2, id);
    deleteDuplicates(s3, id);
  }
}

function deleteDuplicates(sheet, id) {
  var idCol = 1; // Assuming location of ID column is same in all sheets.
  var rowCount = sheet.getLastRow();
  for (var i = 2; i <= rowCount; i++) {
    var data = sheet.getRange(i, idCol, 1, 1).getValue();
    if (data === id) {
      // Use this to test out the function.
      Logger.log("Duplicate of ID " + id + " in sheet " + 
          sheet.getSheetName() + " at row " + i);
      // Uncomment the next line when ready.
      // sheet.deleteRow(i);
    }
  }
}
```

**Logging Output**

```
[14-11-04 09:16:04:551 PST] Duplicate of ID 784 in sheet Sheet2 at row 2
[14-11-04 09:16:04:587 PST] Duplicate of ID 784 in sheet Sheet3 at row 2
[14-11-04 09:16:04:727 PST] Duplicate of ID 901 in sheet Sheet3 at row 5
```

Comment: Thank you @Kayce Basques for the answer. It works as well after modifying a few code. Hope I can accept 2 answers! Thanks again.