# Delete row in other sheets based on 2 values on main file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to delete rows on other sheets based on 2 values? Say I have 3 sheets. In the main sheet (sheet 1), there will be 2 columns: Branch and Manager same with the remaining sheets.

[SAMPLE SPREADSHEET HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PuF77lisYUdzOm-DJh9bLIP-k2yh14jphFEs2tDJE9s/edit?usp=sharing).

Example data:

**SHEET 1: (main sheet)**

```
  ---   BRANCH    ---   MANAGER  ---
      California       Tom Chang
      Brooklyn         Jon Sieg
      New York         Raq Craig
```

**SHEET 2:**

```
  ---   BRANCH    ---   MANAGER  ---
      California       Jane Cali
      California       Tom Chang
      San Francisco    James Chao
```

**SHEET 2:**

```
  ---   BRANCH    ---   MANAGER  ---
      California       Jane Cali
      California       Tom Chang
      New York         Daniel Trevor
```

What should happen is that:

Branch column values should NOT duplicate in all sheets. So what we need to do is delete the row on sheet 2 and 3 if branch column is equal with the main sheet (sheet1) IF AND ONLY IF the manager is not the same/equal. So in my given data above, Branch California and Manager Tom Chang exists in all sheets therefore it should not be touched. But California branch was repeated in the remaining 2 sheets with a different Manager. Therefore, row California ---- Jane Cali should be deleted on Sheets 2 and 3.

Came upon a script borrowed from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26730699/delete-row-values-in-more-than-1-sheet-if-exists-in-another-sheet/26746979#26746979) but can't seem to work. Here:

```
function removeDupsInOtherSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mainsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3").getDataRange().getValues();   
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getDataRange().getValues();  
  var sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3").getDataRange().getValues(); 


  // iterate mainsheet and check in sheet2 & sheet3 if duplicate values exist
  var nsheet2 = [];
  var nsheet3 = [];
  var mainsheetCol1 = [];// data in column1 of main sheet
  var mainsheetCol2 = [];// data in column2 of main sheet

  for(var n in mainsheet){
    mainsheetCol1.push(mainsheet[n][0]); //column1
    mainsheetCol2.push(mainsheet[n][3]); //column2
  }
  for(var n in sheet2){ // iterate sheet2 and test col 1 vs col 1 and co2 1 vs co2 1in sheet2
    var noDup1 = checkForDup(sheet2[n],mainsheetCol1,mainsheetCol2)
    if(noDup1){nsheet2.push(noDup1)};// if not present in sheet3 then keep
  } 
  for(var n in sheet3){  // iterate sheet3 and test col 1 vs col 1 and co2 1 vs co2  in sheet3
    var noDup2 = checkForDup(sheet3[n],mainsheetCol1,mainsheetCol2)
    if(noDup2){nsheet3.push(noDup2)};// if not present in sheet3 then keep
  }
  // view result
  Logger.log(nsheet2);
  Logger.log(nsheet3);

  // clear and update sheets
  ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getDataRange().clear();
  ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3").getDataRange().clear();
  ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange(1,1,nsheet2.length,nsheet2[0].length).setValues(nsheet2);
  ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3").getRange(1,1,nsheet3.length,nsheet3[0].length).setValues(nsheet3);
}

//Here can't seem to make it work to check if column 2 is not equal to the other sheets
//item is sheet2[n]
// s is mainsheetCol1
// s2 is mainsheetCol2
function checkForDup(item,s,s2){
  Logger.log(s+' = '+item[0]+'  ?')
  Logger.log(s2+' = '+item[1]+'  ?')
    if((s.indexOf(item[0])>-1) && (s2.indexOf(item[1])>-1))){
      return null;
    }
  return item;
}
```

Hoping someone could help/guide me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function removeDuplicate(){

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var mainsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
      var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
      var sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3");
      var masterData = mainsheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 

      var sheetsToCheck = [sheet2,sheet3];  

      for(var i in sheetsToCheck){
        var valuesToCheck = sheetsToCheck[i].getDataRange().getValues();
        for(var j=0;j<valuesToCheck.length;j++){
          for(var k in masterData){
            if(masterData[k][0] == valuesToCheck[j][0] && !(masterData[k][1] == valuesToCheck[j][1])){
              sheetsToCheck[i].deleteRow(j+1);
            }
          }
        }
      }

    }
```

Comment: Hi @kyuzo. I tested your script and it seems to work if the data to be removed is on the top most row ONLY. Say if California | Jane Cali is placed in a row below another data, removing of duplicate won't work. See my question with a sample spreadsheet. Hope you could help me.

Comment: Hi @Cookie. Yeah, the addition in  `sheetsToCheck[i].deleteRow(j+1)` didnt work in the first script I posted. When assigning the `j` variable in the loop with `for(var j in valuesToCheck)` it will result in a string. I've changed the for-loop so `j` is a number, see above. Hopefully it will work now.

Comment: I was able to modify the code a while ago and it worked too. But your solution works as well. I accepted it. Thanks @kyuzo! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Code given at [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26730699/delete-row-values-in-more-than-1-sheet-if-exists-in-another-sheet/26746979#26746979) is not working. I have modified it little bit to make it work. 
Here it is,

```
function removeDupsInOtherSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getDataRange().getValues();  
  var s2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getDataRange().getValues(); 
  var s3 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3").getDataRange().getValues();  
  // iterate s3 and check in s1 & s2 if duplicate values exist
  var nS1 = [];
  var nS2 = [];
  var s3Col1 = [];// data in column1 of sheet3
  for(var n=0; n<s3.length; ++n){ 
    s3Col1.push(s3[n][0]);
  }
  for(var n=0; n<s1.length; ++n){ // iterate sheet1 and test col 1 vs col 1 in sheet3
   var noDup1 = checkForDup(s1[n],s3Col1)
    if(noDup1){nS1.push(noDup1)};// if not present in sheet3 then keep
  } 
  for(var n=0; n<s2.length; ++n){  // iterate sheet2 and test col 1 vs col 1 in sheet3
    var noDup2 = checkForDup(s2[n],s3Col1)
    if(noDup2){nS2.push(noDup2)};// if not present in sheet3 then keep
  }
  Logger.log(nS1);// view result
  Logger.log(nS2);
  ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getDataRange().clear();// clear and update sheets
  ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getDataRange().clear();
  var nS1Length = nS1.length;
  var nS2Length = nS2.length;

 // This is the change needed in code you have copied from,
 **if(nS1 != undefined){
    data = []
    data[0] = nS1;
    var range = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(1,1);
    range.setValues(data);
 }
 if(nS2 != undefined){
    data = []
    data[0] = nS1;
    var range = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange(1,1);
    range.setValues(data);
 }**
}

function checkForDup(item,s){
   Logger.log(s+' = '+item[0]+'  ?')
   if(s.indexOf(item[0])>-1){
     return null;
   }
   return item;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @user1989 for the modified code of the post I've based to. Hope I can vote you up but I just registered here in SO. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @user1989 : could you explain what the code you added as "This is the change needed in code you have copied from" really does ? I don't understand this code... Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sergeinsas In the [previous code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26730699/delete-row-values-in-more-than-1-sheet-if-exists-in-another-sheet/26746979#26746979), user were trying to add array in a row, but that is not possible as he was doing. According to that code, he has to use array of array to make it work.

Comment: since you wrote `var range = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(1,1);` and then write to that range an array of array with possibly a lot of cells I'm afraid it won't work... quite obviously. Have you tested your script ?

Comment: @Sergeinsas yes, I have tested this edited script, it's working for me.

Comment: OK, thanks for your answers, I'm surprised but it doesn't matter :-)